# Facebook list of 'Restricted' contacts?

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to get a list of Facebook contacts that are labelled as 'Restricted' in one's account?

Comment: By `one's account` do you mean a list of **another user's** restricted contacts? If so, it's surely not possible for privacy reasons.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how I do it:

- Go to your lists at https://www.facebook.com/bookmarks/lists
- Click on the Restricted list
- In the `Manage List` menu in the upper right corner, select Edit List

You should now see the friends who are `On This List`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot see how does another person manage their lists (i.e. how many lists theey have, what are their names and which contact is in each list)